# npm start is not working in buildroot target

Tags: webpack, npm-install, buildroot

I'm trying to run react application in buildroot Embedded system, but always I get webpack errors
I install packages with the following command :
$(NPM) install --arch=arm64 --target_arch=arm64 --target_platform=linux --target_libc=glibc -g path

When I start app from my board I get this error :
cd /var/www
npm start

```
Starting the development server...

/var/www/node_modules/react-scripts/scripts/start.js:19
  throw err;
  ^

SyntaxError: Invalid regular expression: /^[_\p{L}][_0-9\p{L}]*$/: Invalid property name in character class
    at getGlobalObject (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuntimeTemplate.js:64:11)
    at new RuntimeTemplate (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/RuntimeTemplate.js:85:23)
    at new Compilation (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compilation.js:914:26)
    at Compiler.createCompilation (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1110:35)
    at Compiler.newCompilation (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1118:28)
    at /var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1166:29
    at Hook.eval [as callAsync] (eval at create (/var/www/node_modules/tapable/lib/HookCodeFactory.js:33:10), <anonymous>:4:1)
    at Hook.CALL_ASYNC_DELEGATE [as _callAsync] (/var/www/node_modules/tapable/lib/Hook.js:18:14)
    at Compiler.compile (/var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/Compiler.js:1161:28)
    at /var/www/node_modules/webpack/lib/Watching.js:214:19
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! app22@0.1.0 start: `react-scripts start`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the app22@0.1.0 start script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.


npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     /root/.npm/_logs/2022-11-24T11_07_32_603Z-debug.log
```

I tried to remove node-modules in the board and try npm install, but i got the same error!

This my package.json, by the way i had extra dependencies not needed i removed them by npm remove.

```
{
  "name": "app22",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@chakra-ui/alert": "^2.0.9",
    "@chakra-ui/react": "^2.3.2",
    "@headlessui/react": "^1.6.6",
    "@heroicons/react": "^1.0.6",
    "@progress/kendo-react-dropdowns": "^5.5.0",
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.4",
    "@testing-library/react": "^13.3.0",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "@userfront/react": "^0.3.1",
    "axios": "^0.27.2",
    "bootstrap": "^5.1.3",
    "dayjs": "^1.11.5",
    "heroicons": "^2.0.10",
    "heroicons-react": "^1.4.1",
    "i18next": "^21.9.1",
    "i18next-browser-languagedetector": "^6.1.5",
    "i18next-http-backend": "^1.4.1",
    "react": "^18.2.0",
    "react-bootstrap": "^2.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-i18next": "^11.18.5",
    "react-router-dom": "^5.2.0",
    "react-scripts": "^5.0.1",
    "react-table": "^7.8.0",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.4"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "dev-server": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "cors": "^2.8.5",
    "express": "^4.18.1",
    "tailwindcss": "^3.1.8",
    "webpack-cli": "^5.0.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: Update nodejs  version solve the problem.